# Change tooltip when gold badge holder re-opens a duplicate

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, dupehammer, tooltips

At the moment the text for the tooltip when a gold badge holder re-opens a question is the same as when they close it: *Users with the [tag] gold badge can single-handedly mark [tag] questions as duplicates*...

[image: post revision history example]

Now while it's fairly obvious it's a re-open (the **Post Reopened** bit being a bit of a give away) - would this not be better phrased as:

*Users with the [tag] gold badge can single-handedly re-open [tag] questions marked as duplicates*

Or other more suitably accurate wording?

Comment: This might be better tagged as a bug report or feature request rather than simply as discussion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new updates to the dupehammer notice now indicate that users with the tag can both close *and reopen* questions as duplicates.